# How do i match results from diferent Viewdata

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have got data from 2 different SQL searches in 2 separate ViewDatas ("R_Outout" and "M_Output").Within in each, is a column Room_id.

What I would like to do in the view is query these values, and if they match , show the corresponding result of another column.

At the moment , I get this output (straight from viewdata M-Output)

```
Room ID   Date from   Date to   repair ID   notes 
   5      05/01/2017 06/01/2017   5 
  20      01/11/2016 15/11/2016   5 
  14      27/10/2016 15/11/2016   3
```

etc

What I'm trying to get is the corresponding room number from the rooms id in the 2nd viewdata output (r_output).

```
Room      Date from   Date to   repair ID   notes 
 101      05/01/2017 06/01/2017   5 
 220      01/11/2016 15/11/2016   5 
  45      27/10/2016 15/11/2016   3
```

Ive tried this

```
    @foreach (var item in ViewData["M_Output"] as IEnumerable<app.Models.SP_RESULTS.MT>)
{
    <tr>
        @foreach (var inneritem in ViewData["R_Output"] as IEnumerable<app.Models.SP_RESULTS.rm>)
            {
            <td>
                @if (inneritem.room_id == item.room_id)
            {
                    @inneritem.room_no
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.date_from.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.date_to.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
            </td>
etc...
            }
    </tr>
}
```

what I get out is multiple copies of the table, with the odd room number instead of the id.
I understand that I might have my Foreach's and If, in the wrong place(s), but I have having trouble figuring out where they should be.

could someone help me?

UPDATE: so instead of this 
[image]

I get this

[image]

Comment: You want common (based on room id value) from both the sets ? What is your expected output specifically ?

Comment: hi @Shyju , so if M_output.Room_id = r_Output.room_id ,then display r_output.Room_no, in the first <TD>, then output the rest of the data for that row in M_Output. then do the same on the next pass for the next row in M_Output...untilll the rows in m_output have finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to print all the rows from `M_Output` collection and if there is a matching record in `R_Outout` collection, you want to print the RoomNo value from that.

You can do a LINQ Left join expression to do that.

```
@{
    var mtSet= ViewData["M_Output"] as IEnumerable<app.Models.SP_RESULTS.MT>;        

    var rmSet = ViewData["R_Output"] as IEnumerable<app.Models.SP_RESULTS.rm>;

    var result = (from m in mtSet
                   join r in rmSet on m.room_id equals r.room_id into gj
                   from s in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()    
                   select new { RoomId = p.room_id, 
                                FromDate=p.date_from, 
                                RoomNo= s?.room_no ?? null}).ToList();

}

<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in result)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.RoomId </td>
            <td>@item.FromDate.ToString()</td>
            <td>@item.RoomNo</td>    
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

In the above linq LEFT join expression, i am projecting the results to an anonymous object with `RoomId`,`RoomNo` and `FromDate` properties. You may create a view model which has that structure and project to that.

I personally do not like to put a lot of C# code in my views. I like to keep my views more HTMLy and keep my c# code to minimum. I would put the join code inside the action method and pass only the desired result to the view. I would create the view model with those properties needed (mentioned in the above paragraph) and create a list of that view model from the linq expression and pass that to the view instead of using the view model.

Assuming you have a view model like this

```
public class RoomVm
{
  public int RoomId { set;get;}
  public DateTime FromDate { set;get;}
  public int? RoomNo { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your action method

```
 var result = (from m in mtSet
                join r in rmSet on m.room_id equals r.room_id into gj
                from s in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()    
                select new RoomVm { RoomId = p.room_id, 
                                    FromDate=p.date_from, 
                                    RoomNo= s?.room_no ?? null}
              ).ToList();
 return View(result);
```

and in the view, just loop through the Model

```
@model List<RoomVm>
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.RoomId </td>
            <td>@item.FromDate.ToString()</td>
            <td>@item.RoomNo</td>    
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, I get error in the following lines :    `                   join r in rmSet on m.room_id equals r.room_id into gj` - VS stays room_id (both) do not exist on the Viewdata.  , and `    @foreach (var item in result)` - foreach statement cannot operate on ?

Comment: Did you cast your ViewData item to List<app.Models.SP_RESULTS.rm>` and List of `<app.Models.SP_RESULTS.MT>` .The type of `mtSet` and `rsSet` should be list of those entities. That is what i am doing in the first 2 lines of the code in the view

Comment: hi, Yes. I followed the code above, to the letter. error says "IEnumerable<SP_RESULTS.MT> does no contain a definition for "room_id" and no extension methos "room_id" accepting a first argument of type "IEnumerable<SP_RESULTS.MT> could be found.

Comment: Then it should not complain about that error. You are not using ViewData in your LINQ query. You are using 2 collection local variables (that is what the casting does)